# Does HttpServletRequestWrapper work with RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, model-view-controller, httprequest

I have a requirement where the back-end Spring controller is expecting certain values in the request header, i.e certain custom headers.

The view, a jsp has a html form which will submit the parameters from the end user to the controller. Since it is not possible to send custom headers from an html form or javascript function without using XMLHttpHeader. I cannot use XMLHttpHeader in this case since that will be an AJAX call and in my case i want a form submit.

The only option left for me is, add a mediator servlet which will intercept the call from the jsp, read the values from the request parameter and then add them as request headers and forward them to the final controller. Since it is not possible to add custom header in HttpServletRequest, i used HttpServletRequestWrapper as given in the 
[example](http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/how-to-modify-request-headers-in-a-j2ee-web-application/).

The problem is to forward it to the Spring controller , the following code

```
MockHttpRequestWrapper req = new MockHttpRequestWrapper(request);
req.addHeader("REMOTE_USER", ssoId);
req.addHeader("REALM", realmId);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
dispatcher.forward(req, response);
```

where MockHttpRequestWrapper is a type of HttpServletRequestWrapper as per the example

```
public class MockHttpRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

private Map customHeaderMap = null;

public MockHttpRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
     customHeaderMap = new HashMap();
}

 public void addHeader(String name,String value){
      customHeaderMap.put(name, value);
     }

     @Override
     public String getParameter(String name) {
      String paramValue = super.getParameter(name); // query Strings
      if (paramValue == null) {
       paramValue = (String) customHeaderMap.get(name);
      }
      return paramValue;
     }
```

}

I haven't tested the sample with Filters but i expected the same to work with RequestDispatchers. The final controller is called but the headers are not to be found.

Is the same Request object not passed to the controller? IN the controller the code

```
request.getHeader("REMOTE_USER")
```

returns null.

Looking forward to answers to expand my understanding on the subject :)

Comment: You need to understand how Spring MockHttpRequest work first. This api MAY NOT for your purpose. To implement you purpose, just create Filter to override getHeader function using HttpServletRequestWrapper.

Comment: @Loc thanks for the response. I think there was a confusion over the type of object MockHttpRequest is . So renamed it to MockHttpRequestWrapper. Though it is a Spring project, yet the current task as nothing much to do with Spring. I just want to forward via RequestDispatcher to a Spring controller which has the given RequestMapping. So do you mean that RequestDispatcher wont work and only filters can